# Whats the period with red backgroud meaning in R?

Tags: r

I want to replace the vertical tab in the .txt dataset with \n, but always get warning with:

> Error in dir.exists(x) : file name conversion problem -- name too
> long?

There is a solution for the problem, but I can't find a specific meaning of the period.
[image]
And how should I type this into Rstudio?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to pass to `fread()`? A list of file names? That warning is not related to the marked character. It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just warning you that you have an "invisible" character there. It's a whitespace character that doesn't really have a way to be visually represented. If you prefer, you can use `"\v"` to get the same value. (Note the Stack Overflow editor seems to strip out the vertical tab character when I try to type it into the question so i've re-created the value as `x`, but if you cat the value,  you should see the expanded representation)

```
x <- rawToChar(as.raw(c(0x61, 0x0b, 0x62)))
print(x)
cat(x)
identical("a\vb", x)
[1] TRUE
```

You see here it's hard to tell that there's something other than a space between the "a" and "b". but if you do

```
charToRaw(x)
[1] 61 0b 62
charToRaw("a b")
[1] 61 20 62
```

You can see the two strings have different characters in the second position and RStudio highlight's the "unusual" whitespace character in the first version
[image]

Comment: Yeah you are right! I just copied the "vt" shown in Notepat++ and got the same symbol. But I still get the same error when I use \v in Rstudio with the following code:

gsub(pattern = "\\v", replacement = "\n") 

It only works out, if i replace "\\v" with the kopied symbol. But thanks for your answer!

Comment: If I use `gsub("\v", "\n", x)` with the data above the replacement works for me. You don't need an extra escape. Just one slash for the v and n.